# Understanding the T + 3 settlement days rule

Tags: canada, cash, margin, online-trading, settling-and-clearing

If I:

Buy X at time T

Sell X at time T' where T' < T +3

Buy Y on T' with proceeds from sale of X.

Cannot sell Y before T' +3.

Ref:http://www.slideshare.net/mring33/using-java
Slide 29

It refers to Cash Accounts, which means in margin accounts, I am not subject to this rule?
Also,does it apply only to US stocks or also Canadian stocks. How about US options and Canadian options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For margin, it is correct that these rules do not apply.  The real problem becomes day trading funding when one is just starting out, broker specific minimums.

Options settle in T+1.

One thing to note: if Canada is anything like the US, US options may not be available within Canadian borders.  Foreign derivatives are usually not traded in the US because of registration costs.  However, there may be an exception for US-Canadian trade because one can trade Canadian equities directly within US borders.

Comment: Who says $25K is required? Sounds like something jurisdiction specific. Supporting reference? Also, FWIW, I buy U.S.-listed options all the time. I'm a Canadian and I use a Canadian discount broker.

Comment: @quantycuenta: Thanks. Can you please explain what is a walking order, i could not find any info in google.

Comment: @Victor It's a technique used by active traders to play market maker before hitting the best opposing order.  One can walk orders from the best order on the same side to the opposing side and sometimes get filled by either another active trader directly or indirectly through a market maker using one order to hedge another.

Answer (score 3):

The key word you forgot to include from Slide 29 is:

> Free-Riding

[Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/f/free_rider_problem.asp) defines free-riding as:

> In the context of a brokerage firm, a free rider problem refers to a situation where a client has been allowed to purchase shares without actually paying for them, and then subsequently sells the shares (ideally for profit).
>
> The problem with this scenario is that the client, if allowed to free ride, can profit from a stock trade without actually using any of his or her own capital. This is illegal.

I have not heard of any issues with this type of action being a problem with trading accounts in Australia, nor have I been able to find any such rules on the ASX website or any of by brokers websites. So I think this may be an issue in the USA but not Australia. You should check the rules in any other countries you wish to trade in.

Comment: In Canada it's in NI 23-101 companion policy.  The rule makes very little sense anywhere and I'm not sure how often it's enforced at Canadian brokers.  There are many anecdotes of people actively trading in their RRSP and those are all cash accounts.